# Make custom field meta not display if there is not data in it

Tags: php, posts, custom-field

I current have a custom field that is displaying even if there is not data inputted in the meta box when posting.

[image]

How do I remove the hr, title, and ul if there is not data input?
Here's the code I have currently to pull in the custom field:

```
<?php if( have_rows('google_drive_links') ): ?>
<hr />
     <h3>Attachments</h3>
     <ul class="google-drive-links">
<?php while( have_rows('google_drive_links') ): the_row(); 
     // vars
     $content = get_sub_field('google_link_name');
     $link = get_sub_field('google_link'); ?>
     <li class="google-drive-link-item">
     <a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $link; ?>"><?php echo $content; ?></a>
    </li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: What is the type of that custom field? Is there minimal number of rows set for that field? Because you already check if there are some values - you just don’t remove empty rows...

Comment: I think thats the part I'm confused about. It's a repeater Advanced Custom Fields with a name and link for each row that will repeat in the post area. For some reason it's still returning something even if the meta box is left blank @KrzysiekDróżdż

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that there are rows being returned for:

```
have_rows('google_drive_links')
```

but then, nothing returned for the sub fields?

```
$content = get_sub_field('google_link_name');
$link = get_sub_field('google_link');
```

Perhaps you could put in an extra check for those two before creating the hr and ul?

```
if (get_sub_field('google_link_name') &&  get_sub_field('google_link')){
   // Create the hr and ul 
}
```

Depending on where you want the hr and h3 to appear, possibly like this:

```
<?php if( have_rows('google_drive_links') ): ?>
    <?php while( have_rows('google_drive_links') ): the_row();
         // vars
         $content = get_sub_field('google_link_name');
         $link = get_sub_field('google_link');
         if ($content && $link) : ?>
             <hr />
             <h3>Attachments</h3>
             <ul class="google-drive-links">
                 <li class="google-drive-link-item">
                     <a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $link; ?>"><?php echo $content; ?></a>
                 </li>
             </ul>
         <?php endif; ?>
     <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

If there are multiple rows of links, it should be possible to add a counter to make sure the hr and title is only added once, for example:

```
<?php
$counter = 0;
if( have_rows('google_drive_links') ): ?>
    <?php while( have_rows('google_drive_links') ): the_row();
         // vars
         $content = get_sub_field('google_link_name');
         $link = get_sub_field('google_link');
         if ($content && $link) :
             $counter ++;
             // If there is content and link, create hr and title for first item only, open ul and create li
             if ($counter == 1) : ?>
                 <hr />
                 <h3>Attachments</h3>
                 <ul class="google-drive-links">
             <?php endif; ?>
             <li class="google-drive-link-item">
                 <a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $link; ?>"><?php echo $content; ?></a>
             </li>
         <?php endif; ?>
      <?php
      endwhile;
      if ($counter > 0) : ?>
          <!-- Close ul -->
          </ul>
      <?php endif; ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I think you're right - for some reason when those custom fields are left blank when posting it still must be returning something to make them display. My PHP is a little rusty - where would I add the extra check in comparison to my working code above? Thank you!

Comment: Hi @Collin, I've updated my answer including the check in your code. I haven't tested it yet though...

Comment: That **somewhat** worked! So its now not showing if there is no content. The problem is that, when there is more than 1 "row" of links, they show up with the hr, header, and line [as seen here](https://i.imgur.com/6VbAZAN.png). This is where I keep getting stuck :/ Thanks for the help so far though.

Comment: Hi @Collin, I've added another update. I think you could use a counter to check that the hr and title is only added once if there are multiple rows of links. I haven't tested this yet though, so it might need a bit of tweaking :-)

Comment: It worked!!!!! Thank you :) I've been struggling on this one for a while and my other counterpart that knows PHP better couldn't figure this out either. You're the best!